# XSL template match not working

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a XML document :

```
<Chart>
    <ChartAreas>
        <ChartArea>
           <ChartValueAxes>
                <ChartAxis>
                    <Style>
                        <Border>
                            <Color>Tan</Color>
                         </Border>
                         <FontFamily>Arial Narrow</FontFamily>
                         <FontSize>16pt</FontSize>
                    </Style>
                </ChartAxis>
           </ChartValueAxes>
        </ChartArea>
   </ChartAreas>
</Chart>
```

I have two template match statements as I want the Style/Border element processed by TemplateA and everything else under Style processed by TemplateB. However everything is being processed by TemplateB.

```
<xsl:template match="Chart/ChartAreas/ChartArea/ChartValueAxes/ChartAxis/Style/Border" >
        <xsl:call-template name="TemplateA"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Chart/ChartAreas/ChartArea/ChartValueAxes/ChartAxis/Style" >
     <xsl:call-template name="TemplateB"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mutually exclusives match statements:

```
<xsl:template match="Chart/ChartAreas/ChartArea/ChartValueAxes/ChartAxis/Style/Border" >
        <xsl:call-template name="TemplateA"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Chart/ChartAreas/ChartArea/ChartValueAxes/ChartAxis/Style/*[not(self::Border])]" >
     <xsl:call-template name="TemplateB"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a template that matches the `Style` element itself and calls `TemplateB`.  Therefore (unless `TemplateB` does so explicitly) nothing is causing templates to be applied to the *children* of `Style`, so the `Border` template never fires.

> I want the Style/Border element processed by TemplateA and everything else under Style processed by TemplateB

In that case your templates should be

```
<xsl:template priority="10"
    match="Chart/ChartAreas/ChartArea/ChartValueAxes/ChartAxis/Style/Border" >
        <xsl:call-template name="TemplateA"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template priority="5"
    match="Chart/ChartAreas/ChartArea/ChartValueAxes/ChartAxis/Style/*" >
        <xsl:call-template name="TemplateB"/>
</xsl:template>
```

(I've used explicit priorities because both these rules could apply to the `Border` element and they have the same [default priority](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#conflict))

You can shorten the match expressions, e.g. `match="Style/*"` - you don't need the full path as there are no other Style elements elsewhere that might confuse things.

But even simpler would just be to remove the `call-template` and put the `match` expressions on `TemplateA` and `TemplateB` directly - a template can have both a `name` and a `match`

```
<xsl:template match="Style/Border" name="TemplateA" priority="10">
        <!-- content of template A -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Style/*" name="TemplateB" priority="5">
        <!-- content of template B -->
</xsl:template>
```